# run stack plugin on mouse hover on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am using the following plugin

http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-notes/demo.html

which gives a very good stack, but the problem is when I use it for my gallery. All of the albums are auto rotating which looks odd. Is there any possible way to at least run the plugin after we hover on the div instead of auto run? The main code to run this is

```
$(function(){
    $('.notes_img').mobilynotes({
        init: 'rotate',
        showList: false,
        positionMultiplier: 5
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you read the notes: http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-notes.html

Comment: @ epascarello yes i read the notes it has option of autoplay but if we disable it , the stack dnt work , and if enable it it works all the time , i want it to work on mouse hover on div ? can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hiya sakshi okies will code a small jsfiddle for your dire need mate: - so all you need is - on hover start stacking up yea? cheerios!

Comment: yes @Tats_innit i tried to put up some code but it didnt worked properly . and i cant seem to find a solution . thanks for the help

Comment: @SakshiSharma no probs see my answer below, hope it helps cheeriosness & dont forget to upvote and accpet if that helps :)) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya there so **demo here** :) and hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/14/show/ && http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/14/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/3/show/ && http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/3/

Now the rotation will start when you hover the images and if you want further that one mouse out it should stop you can take a look into event `.mouseout` and you can stop the rotation i.e. remove the effect.

Like epascarello mentioned documentation is here http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-notes.html

Please let me know and dont forget to accept if this helps (and upvote :)) cheers

**Jquery Code**

```
$('.notes_img').hover(function() {
    $('.notes_img').mobilynotes({
        init: 'rotate',
        showList: false
    });

});​
```

Comment: soory to say but it not working friend . in your jsfiddle also it rotating on it own even if the mouse is not over

Comment: @SakshiSharma yep you can use `.mouseout` event to stop it lolz, I did gave you idea in case you only want them to rotate them on `mouseover` anywho do you know how to do that? **or** should I take a look cheerios!

Comment: @SakshiSharma http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/14/show/ here you go now it will only work on hover :) cheers!

Comment: thanks for the help . but in this code the stack album css does loads up until mouseover , can it be possible to keep the stack css and load stack animation on mouseover ? hope u getting my point like when we mouse over the autoplay becomes true atleast by this when we are not using mouse over the stack css remains

Comment: can u please help me with the mouse out to stop animation ? m almost there to make it work with css and animation

Comment: Hiya @SakshiSharma howz it? please try using `autoplay: false` property; yep will take a look into this latter :) after dinner might be; I have to read the .js file for this plugin but you should play around with this plugin pretty simple innit :)) Take care, Cheerios!

Comment: This solution appears to give completely erratic behaviour.

Comment: Hiya @Beetroot-Beetroot bruv before giving down vote atleast give some reason man - erratic what sort of?? cheerios and have a good one!

Comment: Maybe it's just the browser I'm using (Opera) but the stack just goes wild on me after first mouseover. With repeated mouseovers it gets even wilder. "Erratic", "wild" - either term accurately describes what I see.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot all good bruv no worries - any who if you want can you please don't down vote coz I did spent some time to actually help for this answer! Have a good one! cheerios :)

Comment: Fix it and I'll be happy to give you +1.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot lol I am finding it hard to see the behavior bruv its real late at my end might take a look sometime tomorrow! have a good one - I still think if you want anything constructive you should make changes on the jsfiddle and produce correct behaviour. Take care man! cheerios

Answer (score 2):

**Notice:** I am not the author but it's an MIT licensed plugin so there shouldn't be any problem with modifying and redistributing it here.

In spite of eye candy of the plugin, it's not elastic enough to extend. 
You can use my modified version instead.

mobilynotes.js:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.mobilynotes = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            init: "rotate",
            positionMultiplier: 5,
            title: null,
            showList: true,
            autoplay: true,
            interval: 4000,
            hover:    true,
            index:    1
        };
        var sets = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var $t = $(this),
                note = $t.find(".note"),
                size = note.length,
                autoplay;
            var notes = {
                init: function () {
                    notes.css();
                    if (sets.showList) {
                        notes.list()
                    }
                    if (sets.autoplay) {
                        notes.autoplay()
                    }
                    if (sets.hover) {
                        notes.hover()
                    }
                    notes.show()
                },
                random: function (l, u) {
                    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (u - l + 1)) + l)
                },
                css: function () {
                    var zindex = note.length;
                    note.each(function (i) {
                        var $t = $(this);
                        switch (sets.init) {
                        case "plain":
                            var x = notes.random(-(sets.positionMultiplier), sets.positionMultiplier),
                                y = notes.random(-(sets.positionMultiplier), sets.positionMultiplier);
                            $t.css({
                                top: y + "px",
                                left: x + "px",
                                zIndex: zindex--
                            });
                            break;
                        case "rotate":
                            var rotate = notes.random(-(sets.positionMultiplier), sets.positionMultiplier),
                                degrees = "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)";
                            $t.css({
                                "-webkit-transform": degrees,
                                "-moz-transform": degrees,
                                "-o-transform": degrees,
                                filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=" + rotate + ")",
                                zIndex: zindex--
                            })
                        }
                        $t.attr("note", i)
                    })
                },
                zindex: function () {
                    var arr = new Array();
                    note.each(function (i) {
                        arr[i] = $(this).css("z-index")
                    });
                    var z = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
                    return z
                },
                list: function () {
                    $t.after($("<ul />").addClass("listNotes"));
                    var ul = $t.find(".listNotes"),
                        title = new Array();
                    if (sets.title != null) {
                        note.each(function (i) {
                            title[i] = $(this).find(sets.title).text()
                        })
                    } else {
                        title[0] = "Bad selector!"
                    }
                    for (x in title) {
                        $t.next(".listNotes").append($("<li />").append($("<a />").attr({
                            href: "#",
                            rel: x
                        }).text(title[x])))
                    }
                },
                autoplay: function () {
                    var i = 1,
                        autoplay = setInterval(function () {
                            i == size ? i = 0 : "";
                            var div = note.eq(i),
                                w = div.width(),
                                left = div.css("left");
                            notes.animate(div, w, left);
                            i++
                        }, sets.interval)
                },
                hover: function () {
                    $t.hover(function() {
                        var div = note.eq(sets.index),
                        w = div.width(),
                        left = div.css("left");
                        sets.index == size ? sets.index = 1 : sets.index += 1;
                        notes.animate(div, w, left);
                    },
                    function() {}
                    );
                },
                show: function () {
                    $t.next(".listNotes").find("a").click(function () {
                        var $t = $(this),
                            nr = $t.attr("rel"),
                            div = note.filter(function () {
                                return $(this).attr("note") == nr
                            }),
                            left = div.css("left"),
                            w = div.width(),
                            h = div.height();
                        clearInterval(autoplay);
                        notes.animate(div, w, left);
                        return false
                    })
                },
                animate: function (selector, width, position) {
                    var z = notes.zindex();
                    selector.animate({
                        left: width + "px"
                    }, function () {
                        selector.css({
                            zIndex: z + 1
                        }).animate({
                            left: position
                        })
                    })
                }
            };
            notes.init()
        })
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Using new features:

```
$('.notes_img').mobilynotes({
        init: 'rotate',
        showList: false,
        autoplay: false,
        index: 1, //starting index (new)
        hover: true // (new)
    });
```

Comment: Hiya @username did you added `:hover` property ? coz I cannot see it in here: http://playground.mobily.pl/assets/demo/notes/js/mobilynotes.js ; try to fit in with the jsfiddle I got, I tried but dint fit in bruv! cheerios,

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I am not the author. I just modified it as asked by OP. Since it's MIT licensed i don't think it would be problem for the author.

Comment: Here you are. Just deleted the reference to mobilynotes.js in html and added whole library to js field. http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/50/ ---  http://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/50/show/

Comment: Hiya @username howz it, Yeah bruv, saweet :) I tried that and about to update you as well **Something like thishttp://jsfiddle.net/haf6J/47/* Nice to see you around man, and yeah I check it MIT licensed no issues there bruv, its a nice change you did send the guy a email for pull request for this change, although check the exact behaviour this question looking for. but good adition there + 1 from my end, CHerrios man!

Comment: @Tats_innit I would prefer that +1 to my answer just for the sake of repwhoring. :)

Comment: lolz okies here you go man!! :)) ha ha +1 but look the behaviour question need might be bit different

Comment: its not working properly in IE can anyone have a solution for that

Answer (score 2):

Taking over where @username left off (excellent work), I have branched username's fiddle with the following changes to the config options:

Modified (from @username's code):

- `hover`: (boolean) on hover, reverses the effect of `autoplay`

New:

- `click`: (boolean) on click, advances to next note, then resumes autoplay, if active, in the hover state.

Internally, new `next`, `stop` and `restart` functions and modified `init`, `autoplay` and `animate` functions handle (combinations of) the options.

The trickiest part was to provide for a callback in `animate` to cause autoplay to resume after `next` (the click action) has completed. This has ramifications in several other functions. *(On reflection there's undoubtedly a better way using `deferreds` - I will have a think about that)*

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqyLG/) (or [this full page version](http://jsfiddle.net/RqyLG/show/)), with settings that reflect @Sakshi Sharma original question. I set `click` to true but it could equally be set to false, depending on preference.

And here's the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mobilynotes = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            init: "rotate",
            positionMultiplier: 5,
            title: null,
            showList: true,
            autoplay: false,
            hover: true,//when true, hovering  reverses autoplay; when false, has no effect.
            click: true,
            interval: 4000,
            index: 1
        };
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var $t = $(this),
                note = $t.find(".note"),
                size = note.length,
                autoplay,
                currentIndex = 1;
            var notes = {
                init: function() {
                    notes.css();
                    if (settings.showList) {
                        notes.list();
                    }
                    if (settings.hover) {
                        var fn1 = settings.autoplay ? notes.stop : notes.restart;
                        var fn2 = settings.autoplay ? notes.restart : notes.stop;
                        $t.hover(fn1, fn2);
                    }
                    if (settings.click) {
                        clearInterval(autoplay);
                        //autoplay 0, hover 0: null
                        //autoplay 0, hover 1: autoplay
                        //autoplay 1, hover 0: autoplay
                        //autoplay 1, hover 1: null
                        var callback = ( (settings.autoplay && !settings.hover) || (!settings.autoplay && settings.hover) ) ? notes.autoplay : null;
                        $t.click(function(){
                            notes.next(callback);
                        });
                    }
                    if (settings.autoplay) {
                        notes.autoplay();
                    }
                    notes.show();
                },
                random: function(l, u) {
                    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (u - l + 1)) + l);
                },
                css: function() {
                    var zindex = note.length;
                    note.each(function(i) {
                        var $t = $(this);
                        switch (settings.init) {
                        case "plain":
                            var x = notes.random(-(settings.positionMultiplier), settings.positionMultiplier),
                                y = notes.random(-(settings.positionMultiplier), settings.positionMultiplier);
                            $t.css({
                                top: y + "px",
                                left: x + "px",
                                zIndex: zindex--
                            });
                            break;
                        case "rotate":
                            var rotate = notes.random(-(settings.positionMultiplier), settings.positionMultiplier),
                                degrees = "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)";
                            $t.css({
                                "-webkit-transform": degrees,
                                "-moz-transform": degrees,
                                "-o-transform": degrees,
                                filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=" + rotate + ")",
                                zIndex: zindex--
                            })
                        }
                        $t.attr("note", i)
                    });
                },
                zindex: function() {
                    var arr = new Array();
                    note.each(function(i) {
                        arr[i] = $(this).css("z-index")
                    });
                    var z = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
                    return z
                },
                list: function() {
                    $t.after($("<ul />").addClass("listNotes"));
                    var ul = $t.find(".listNotes"),
                        title = new Array();
                    if (settings.title != null) {
                        note.each(function(i) {
                            title[i] = $(this).find(settings.title).text()
                        })
                    } else {
                        title[0] = "Bad selector!"
                    }
                    for (x in title) {
                        $t.next(".listNotes").append($("<li />").append($("<a />").attr({
                            href: "#",
                            rel: x
                        }).text(title[x])))
                    }
                },
                next: function(callback) {
                    callback = (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') ? null : callback;
                    currentIndex = currentIndex % size;
                    notes.animate(note.eq(currentIndex), callback);
                    currentIndex++;
                },
                autoplay: function() {
                    notes.stop();
                    autoplay = setInterval(notes.next, settings.interval);
                },
                stop: function() {
                    clearInterval(autoplay);
                },
                restart: function() {
                    notes.next(notes.autoplay);
                },
                show: function() {
                    $t.next(".listNotes").find("a").click(function() {
                        var $t = $(this),
                            nr = $t.attr("rel"),
                            div = note.filter(function() {
                                return $(this).attr("note") == nr;
                            });
                        clearInterval(autoplay);
                        notes.animate(div);
                        return false;
                    })
                },
                animate: function(selector, callback) {
                    var width = selector.width(),
                        position = selector.css("left"),
                        z = notes.zindex();
                    selector.animate({
                        left: width + "px"
                    }, function() {
                        selector.css({
                            zIndex: z + 1
                        }).animate({
                            left: position
                        }, function(){
                            if(callback) {
                                callback();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
            notes.init()
        })
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: ur code working awsome but is there any way this could work in IE8 as in IE8 the images are not coming they way they are instead flipped images are coming

Comment: @Sakshi Sharma, The mobilynotes site says only that init: 'rotate' does not work properly in IE. I didn't try to improve this aspect and can only assume it is impossible otherwise they would have fixed it already. Sorry I can't be much help in this area.

Comment: thanks for answering , i also didnt found any help regarding this . well , thanks for sharing the code .